# Twitter REST API 1.1 Java

Tags: android, twitter

Hi I am trying to consume REST API of Twitter without using the parse Sdk.
I got acess token and acess token secret from parse twitter class ,Can any one tell me what i am doing wrong.

I am using REST api 1.1 of twitter .

```
    private void usingNetwork() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                URL ur = new URL(
                                        "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?  screen_name=suresh_bora&include_entities=true");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) ur
                        .openConnection();
                conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                conn.addRequestProperty(
                        "Authorization",
                        "OAuth oauth_consumer_key="
                                + ParseTwitterUtils.getTwitter()
                                        .getConsumerKey()
                                + ",oauth_token="
                                + ParseTwitterUtils.getTwitter()
                                        .getAuthToken()
                                + ",oauth_nonce=kYjzVBB8Y0ZFdfdfabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg," +
                                "oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1," +
                                "oauth_timestamp="+ new Timestamp(date.getSeconds()) +
                                ",oauth_version=1.0,"+
                                "oauth_signature="+ParseTwitterUtils.getTwitter().getAuthTokenSecret()+"");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                readStream(conn.getInputStream());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

}

Comment: The API version in your URL should be `/1/` and not `/1.1/`.

Comment: No do not work , well i want to use twitter Rest api 1.1

Answer (score 2):

That helped me:

"**SSL absolutely required.**
This manner of authentication is only secure if SSL is used. Therefore, all requests (both to obtain and use the tokens) must use HTTPS endpoints" ((c) https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth)

So you must use HttpsURLConnection instead of Http.
After that check if you get the token, it looks like "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA%2FAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA%3DAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA".

Here's an example:

```
 private final static String getTokenURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
 private static String bearerToken;

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // encodeKeys(APIKEY, APISECRET);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                bearerToken = requestBearerToken(getTokenURL);
                fetchTimelineTweet(twitURL);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IOException e");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

}

// Encodes the consumer key and secret to create the basic authorization key
private static String encodeKeys(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret) {
    try {
        String encodedConsumerKey = URLEncoder.encode(consumerKey, "UTF-8");
        String encodedConsumerSecret = URLEncoder.encode(consumerSecret,
                "UTF-8");

        String fullKey = encodedConsumerKey + ":" + encodedConsumerSecret;
        byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(fullKey.getBytes());

        return new String(encodedBytes);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return new String();
    }
}

// Constructs the request for requesting a bearer token and returns that
// token as a string
private static String requestBearerToken(String endPointUrl)
        throws IOException {
    HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
    String encodedCredentials = encodeKeys(APIKEY, APISECRET);

    System.out.println("encodedCredentials "+encodedCredentials);
    try {
        URL url = new URL(endPointUrl);
        connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        System.out.println(connection);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "api.twitter.com");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "anyApplication");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "
                + encodedCredentials);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "29");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        writeRequest(connection, "grant_type=client_credentials");

        // Parse the JSON response into a JSON mapped object to fetch fields
        // from.
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(readResponse(connection));

        if (obj != null) {
            String tokenType = (String) obj.get("token_type");
            String token = (String) obj.get("access_token");

            return ((tokenType.equals("bearer")) && (token != null)) ? token
                    : "";
        }
        return new String();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new IOException("Invalid endpoint URL specified.", e);
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}

// Fetches the first tweet from a given user's timeline
private static String fetchTimelineTweet(String endPointUrl)
        throws IOException {
    HttpsURLConnection connection = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(endPointUrl);
        connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "api.twitter.com");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "anyApplication");
         connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " +  bearerToken);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        // Parse the JSON response into a JSON mapped object to fetch fields
        // from.
        JSONArray obj = (JSONArray) JSONValue.parse(readResponse(connection));
        System.out.println("JSON obj = "+obj);

        if (obj != null) {
            String tweet = ((JSONObject) obj.get(0)).get("text").toString();
            System.out.println(tweet);
            return (tweet != null) ? tweet : "";
        }
        return new String();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new IOException("Invalid endpoint URL specified.", e);
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}

// Writes a request to a connection
private static boolean writeRequest(HttpURLConnection connection,
        String textBody) {
    try {
        BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                connection.getOutputStream()));
        wr.write(textBody);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

// Reads a response for a given connection and returns it as a string.
private static String readResponse(HttpURLConnection connection) {
    try {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            str.append(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        return str.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return new String();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @Defurea Thanks for this reply.I will test and then accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

To add to this, you can find the code examples posted above by Defuera and a little more info at: http://www.coderslexicon.com/demo-of-twitter-application-only-oauth-authentication-using-java/

What I was doing wrong was encoding the bearer token as base 64 too, you don't need to do this.

Once you have the bearer token, you can just open up another HttpsUrlConnection to Twitter and handle the response.

What I did personally was just get an Object back and return that to the frontend as json.

If you try to cast to a specific json type, for example if you are using org.simple.json, Twitter returns either a JSON array or JSON object, depending on which REST URL you invoke. So if you try and cast this to JSONObject or JSONArray, it will throw an Exception if you pick the wrong type:

```
private Object requestTwitterApi(String endPointUrl, Map<String, String[]> params)
        throws IOException {

    HttpsURLConnection connection = null;

    // Generate query
    String query = generateQueryUrl(params);
    // Append query to URL
    endPointUrl += query;
    // endPointUrl is now: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40twitterapi for example

    try {
        URL url = new URL(endPointUrl);
        connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        LOGGER.debug("TwitterApiUrl: " + connection);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "api.twitter.com");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "anyApplication");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken); // bearer token is exactly what was returned from Twitter
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        // Parse the JSON response into a JSON mapped object
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = null;
        try {
            obj = parser.parse(readResponse(connection));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            LOGGER.debug("Exception parsing JSON from Twitter");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // then just return the object and I use struts-json-plugin to convert to json and return to frontend. This will allow you to return JSON objects or arrays without issue
        return obj != null ? obj : "";

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Invalid endpoint URL specified : " + e);
        throw new IOException("Invalid endpoint URL specified.", e);
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone, this ended up taken me a whole day just to use the Twitter API... (we are doing custom analytics) Facebook took 30 mins by comparison.